# User can't login after creating them with the asp.net Create User Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

When I create a user, they can't login until I go into the asp.net configuration and save them.  I actually don't change any settings, I just press the save button and then they can login in.  What I would like to do is to have the user be able to login once they are created, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my code for the CreatedUser method:

```
 protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CustomerProfile adminProfile = CustomerProfile.GetProfile();
     string username = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text.Trim();

        CustomerProfile createdUser = CustomerProfile.GetProfile(username);
        createdUser.CustomerID = adminProfile.CustomerID;

        createdUser.Save();

        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);

        user.IsApproved = ((CheckBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("chkActivateUser")).Checked;

        Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "nonadmin");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that after I created the user, the next page would display a message saying the user was created successfully with a continue button.  When I clicked continue it would take me to the login page where I would try to login with the new user, but because it would try to access the admin section when I tried to login with the new user, it would not login.